# How to use group by with case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following fields

CREATE TABLE Tblstock
( ID int    , SlNo int, Storage varchar(10), stock int);

insert into Tblstock values
(1, 1,  'STORE',    100),
(2, 1,  'Floor 1',  20),
(3, 2,  'STORE',    2000),
(4, 2,  'Floor 1',  40);

I have to dynamically update the left over quantity in store after it got consumed on floor1, I have written a code to calculate qty in store using below mentioned query,

SELECT (
(SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(B.SlNo) > 1 OR B.Storage = 'STORE' THEN SUM(B.Stock)END FROM TblStock B GROUP BY B.SlNo) -
(SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(B.SlNo) > 1 OR B.Storage <> 'STORE' THEN SUM(B.Stock)END FROM TblStock B GROUP BY B.SlNo))

However it is not generating the desired result and throwing error

Can anybody help to write it properly so that I get single value of remaining quantity in store

Comment: *"it's not working in MsSql"* What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. Using indentation and line breaks really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's. I have formatted your SQL for you, but get into the habit of doing it yourself.

Comment: What is not working in MsSql ?

Comment: On a separated note `B` is an odd choice of an alias for an object called `TblStock`. I would have gone for `S`, personally, and not put a prefix in the object's name.

Comment: Your 2 subqueries are also expected to return a *scalar* value; I doubt they are considering that they both have a `GROUP BY` clause.  Perhaps these are part of a large query and you should be correlating it? Perhaps you shouldn't be using subqueries at all (probably more likely).

Comment: hi prakash, could you describe what you are trying to do and the expected output? people are eager to help, but if you didnt help them to understand your question, that would be difficult for everyone.

Comment: In your calculation the amounts in store are included in the plus and the minus so they cancel one another out. Perhaps you should try to explain the business logic of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Here is the code for the schema. I post it to save everyone repeating the same work.  I can't make any sense of the query .       `CREATE TABLE Tblstock(
ID int ,
SlNo int,
Storage varchar(10),
stock int);
insert into Tblstock values
(1, 1, 'STORE', 100),
(2, 1, 'Floor 1', 20),
(3, 2, 'STORE', 2000),
(4, 2, 'Floor 1', 40);`

Comment: Thanks you all for your quick and positive reply, although I couldn't able to type on my mobile, i appreciate your efforts and suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a straight-forward grouping and conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT
  s.SlNo,
  Total = SUM(CASE WHEN s.Storage = 'STORE' THEN s.Qty ELSE -s.Qty END)
FROM TblStock s
GROUP BY
  s.SlNo;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fa4564603cc447580e312b51764c0a59)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you are trying to do is to deduct the quantity (qty) in storage called store by the sum of the rest of the other storage. I could think of a query like this:

```
 select *,
     (Qty - (select sum(b.Qty) from tblstock as b
             where b.Storage <> 'store'
                   and b.SINo = a.SINo
             group by b.SINo)) as remainingQty
 from tblstock as a
 where a.Storage = 'store' group by a.SINo
```

The query above, with the following input:

| ID | SINo | Storage | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | store | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | floor 1 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | floor 2 | 30 |
| 4 | 2 | store | 100 |
| 5 | 2 | floor 1 | 40 |
| 6 | 2 | floor 2 | 50 |

It produces the following output:

| ID | SINo | Storage | Qty | remainingQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | store | 100 | 50 |
| 4 | 2 | store | 100 | 10 |

You can find the [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c793ca/1).

Note:

- If you are want to avoid subquery and have the urge to chug in `join` [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c793ca/11):

  ```
  select a.id,
      a.SINo,
      a.Storage,
      a.Qty,
      c.Qty,
      (a.Qty - c.Qty) as remainingQty
  from tblstock as a
  join
       (select b.SINo,
               sum(b.Qty) as Qty
         from tblstock as b
         where b.Storage <> 'store'
         group by b.SINo) as c
  on c.SINo = a.SINo
  where a.Storage = 'store' group by a.SINo
  ```

Comment: Although it seems to be quite easy to create query, but I spent hours figuring out how to write it. Undoubtedly i learnt something new. Thanks for your reply